# plotting already computed histogram with matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, histogram

I compute bins (bin boundary values so for n bins I have n+1 values) and the values of the bins of a histogram but despite of my silly struggle I cannot draw the histogram. Is there any body help me in that situation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your question you mention you already have the bins. Then you should use the `bar` function. That is described in the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/hist.html#btsgtr1-1).